# Jquery Datatable Destroy

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**HTML**

```
<table class="table" id="user_WDdata">
                    <thead class=" text-primary">
                    <tr>
                      <th>
                        Email
                      </th>
                        <th>
                        Wallet Addr
                      </th>
                          <th>
                        Amount
                      </th>
                          <th>
                        Apply Date
                      </th>
                      <th >
                        status
                      </th>
                      <th>
                       Message
                      </th>
            <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
```

**JQuery**

```
 function fetch_data()
  {
   var dataTable = $('#user_WDdata').DataTable({
   "bPaginate": false,
   "info":     false,
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "order" : [],
    "ajax" : {
     url:"WDFetchData.php",

    }
   });
  }
});

 success:function(data)
     {
      $('#MsgModal').modal('toggle');
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
      $('#user_WDdata').DataTable().destroy();
      fetch_data();
     }
```

I want to destroy this datatable and reload the datatable through `fetch_data` function but is not destroying at all. I am also doing this with my other pages, it works fine there. what has happend? What I have done wrong?

Comment: Hi @user, could you improve the title of your post, please? It is gonna help people be interested to answer your question.

Comment: *"it works fine with my other pages"* - what are you doing different here/there ?

Comment: Check your browser's JavaScript console to make sure there aren't any errors

Comment: there is no error sir i have checked

Comment: @freedomn-m sir i mean to say where ever i am using this datatable destroy it works there. but not here

Comment: Exactly.  If it works on your other pages but not here then the other pages have something different.  What's different?